# php mostrar datas e horarios e fone nos formatos

Tags: php, string

precios mostrar na tela algumas informaçoes tipo:

$hora = '120034'
$data = '20170508'
$mes  = '201704'
$fome = '62992161424'

como faço pra mostrar assim 
echo $hora    12:00:34 
echo $data    08/05/2017 
echo $mes     04/2017 
echo $fone   62-99216-1424

echo date('m/y',strtotime no mes nao funciona 
o unico que fucionou foi o valor usando format

Answer (score 1):

[**Veja no Ideone**](https://ideone.com/ghTSYN)

```
$hora = '120034';
$data = '20170508';
$mes = '201704';
$fome = '62992161424';

$array = str_split($hora, 2); 
$string = implode(":", $array);
echo $string; 

$ano = substr($data, 0, 4);
$mez = substr($data, 4, 2);
$dia = substr($data, 6, 2);
$string = $dia . "/" . $mez . "/" . $ano;
echo $string;

$ano = substr($mes, 0, 4);
$month = substr($mes, 4, 2);
$string = $month . "-" . $ano;
echo $string;

$dois = substr($fome, 0, 2);
$cinco = substr($fome, 2, 5);
$quatro = substr($fome, 7, 4);

$string = $dois . "-" . $cinco . "-" . $quatro;
echo $string;
```

- [str_split](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-split.php) — Converte uma string para um array com um comprimento predeterminado de cada elemento do array
- [substr()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php) Retorna uma parte de uma string

[**teste na versão PHP desejada aqui**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/57fcf1b921cb94d06073562234b15ffab06249ce)